# Count(*) with NText column is very very very slow. Why is it so slow? And how can I improve performance?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I've got some problems with my SQL Server 2005 database. I've got a table with order lines and every line has an `NTEXT` field named `XmlData`. I want to count all the fields that have no information stored in them. I'm using this query:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM [OrderLine] WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE [XmlData] NOT LIKE '' AND [XmlData] IS NOT NULL
```

The table has 230.314 of records and this counting query it takes several minutes. Do any of you guys have a clue as how to increase performance?

Note: I can't change to type of the column to `nvarchar(max)` type. The NOLOCK was a tip of a colleague.

I'm looking forward to some tips and explanations.

Comment: Why are you using `NOT LIKE` to compare with the empty string?

Comment: **WHY** can't you change it to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`?? This (or changing it to `XML`) would be your best bet! `NTEXT` is messy, slow, no longer supported - get rid of it!

Comment: do you have any system that can't be changed that depends on this field being ntext? or if you explain why this change would be beneficial you would be able to change its type?

Comment: It looks more and more that there are no reasons not to change to NVARCHAR(MAX) (that's a lot of no's). I'll be looking into the deprecation of the NTEXT and the use of NVARCHAR(MAX) or XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the expensive LOB reads, replace `[XmlData] NOT LIKE ''` with `DATALENGTH([XmlData])>0` - [`DATALENGTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) doesn't need to read in the LOB value of each row.

Also, as others have suggested: use nvarchar(max) instead of ntext, if possible.

Comment: Yes! We have a performance increase. DataLength is better than the NOT LIKE '' AND IS NOT NULL.

Comment: FYI: If you want a faster XmlData IS NULL you'll need to do a DATALENGTH([XmlData]) IS NULL.

Answer (score 2):

NTEXT is deprecated, use nvarchar(max) instead (consider xml ...).

If you change your column type you can create an index on the column, thus creating statistics for the column will help SQL choose the best way to use this index.

Create Statistics for the XMLData column, as this creates a map of values that will increase the of the count type of queries significantly.

```
CREATE STATISTICS STATOrderLineXmlData
ON OrderLine (XmlData)
WITH FULLSCAN
```

Based on @Pent's answer you should change your query for this one:
Replace the query for this:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM [OrderLine] WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE [XmlData] IS NOT NULL 
AND DATALENGTH([XmlData]) > 0
```

Check [this Link](http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsPerfBlog/archive/2008/04/16/ntext-vs-nvarcharmax-in-sql-2005.aspx) if you're changing the column type for nvarchar(max).
The Link has info around a little tricky update you have to do to gain performance after the column change.

Comment: @Gabriel this is the exact query

Comment: @Kees have you created the statistics for the ntext field?

Comment: @Gabrial, no I haven't created any statistics for the field.

Comment: @Kees please do create it, you can get the script on my answer.

Comment: Statistics only affect the query plan, not the actualy execution speed, so they aren't going to help here. `COUNT` queries don't run on the statistics, but on the actual data.

Comment: @Pent thanks, I get it, but this will help SQL choose the best index for a count(*) with this column, right?

Comment: @Gabriel It's not possible to create an index on a ntext column.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this query is going to involve a table scan. That is going to be slow with 230K rows. You can try replacing NOT LIKE with Length(XmlData) = 0, but I don't think that is going to help much. On the other hand, I'm not sure the Length function works with NText data types. I don't think it does, now that I think about it.

The bottom line is that table scans are slow, and dealing with NText data types is slow. So you have a bad combination here. I don't see much room for improvement here, unless the data type can be changed.

And, I'm sure you probably realize that using WITH NOLOCK runs the risk of reading dirty data? Yes it can help performance, but it's not free. You might be reading uncommitted changes.

Comment: The length solution gives me the same results in the Execution plan. It seems the table scan is still the worst thing:

Used:
SELECT Count(*) FROM [OrderLine] WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE len(XmlData] as nvarchar(1))) = 0

The reading of dirty data is no problem with this count.